# Avoid null ref in recursive call

Tags: javascript

I've recursive call and I want to be safe (in case that my func will be null which will cause an error),currently I use the call to the function inside the function itself which can have some ref problem in case of null,there is a way to make this call safe in JS?

e.g.

```
myFunc("hello",1);

function myFunc(){
  myFunc();
}
```

i've tried to find in the web some ways to overcome this but didnt find...

Comment: Could you explain why myFunc can be null inside of myFunc(){}?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In this case I would use the arguments.callee like following

```
function myFunc(){
  arguments.callee();
}
```

This give you the reference of the function and you don't need to use the function name.

Let me know if this solve your problem.

Update - As Pr0gr4mm3r said in comment below this is not available in ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode
Good luck!

Comment: Just to mention it. arguments.callee is forbidden in ES5 strict mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can ensure you have a reference to `myFunc` using a closure:

```
var myFunc = (function() {
    function myFunc() {
        myFunc();
    }
    return myFunc;
})();

// demo
var tmp = myFunc;
myFunc = null;
tmp(); // infinite recursion
```

If you don't need to support IE8 and below, a named function expression is nicer and does the job:

```
var myFunc = function myFunc() {
    myFunc();
};
```

Unfortunately IE8 has a bug which prevents this from working (see [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs) by Juriy "kangax" Zaytsev and blogpost [Double-take](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html)).